# result of cypher query on neoism golang

Tags: go, neo4j, cypher, neoism

I have a function to delete "User" node and return count deleted node, but it always return -1.

```
func DeleteUser(userid int) (int, error) {
        stmt := `
        MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.userId = {userid} delete u RETURN count(u) ;
        `
        params := neoism.Props{"userid": userid}
        res := -1
        cq := neoism.CypherQuery{
            Statement:  stmt,
            Parameters: params,
            Result:     &res,
        }

        err := conn.Cypher(&cq)

        return res, err
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) res must be of type []struct

2)  Don't use ";" at the end of query.
stmt := `MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.userId = {userid} delete u RETURN count(u)`

Comment: if we user  `[]struct{quantity int}`, we must `return res[0].quantity`, right?

Comment: yes !! And there  is a sample code.. Try to understand